# Phonegap build XML request

Tags: javascript, android, html, xml, cordova

I use the fallowing code to get information from a XML file.
It does work on my laptop and loading the html file directly with the file browser.
However it does not work with an app created by phonegap build.
I'm working with android 4.3. Hope someone knows the answer.

```
var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest()
Connect.open("GET", "data/test.xml", false);
Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
Connect.send(null);
var TheDocument = Connect.responseXML;
var workid = TheDocument.childNodes[0];
for (var i = 0; i < workid.children.length; i++)
{
var id = workid.children[i];
var Name = id.getElementsByTagName("title");
document.write(Name[0].textContent.toString());
  }
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: You get any messages in Debug window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people having the same problem:Got it working using the following code.

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
} 
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="frame">

<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("test.xml");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
document.write(x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
alert('loaded');
</script>

</div>

</body>
```